# Restful Webservice @Pathparam if blank always give 404 error

Tags: java, web-services, glassfish

I am following this example for builiding my first restful webservice

http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/06/03/exception-handling-in-jax-rs-resteasy-with-exceptionmapper/

**This is the method

```
@Path("/users/{id}")
@GET
@ValidateRequest
public Response getUserBId  ( @PathParam("id") String id ) throws    MyApplicationException
{
```

I am using the following softwares

Neatbeans 7.4
Glassfish 4.0

Everything works fine if i pass a value in Id but if i dont pass value in ID , i always end with Error 404

```
GET RequestFailed RequestFailed --> Status: (404) 
Response: {
HTTP Status 404 - Not Found
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type Status report

messageNot Found

descriptionThe requested resource is not available.

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.0
```

How to capture it and show my own error.

Could any one help me in this,as i am very new to this.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the explanation @Razh and @FazoMisiek, i got your point.

but If we have following situation   

`code`
    1) If there are 3 paramaters and if i leave 1 blank 

    public Response getUserBId  ( @PathParam("id") String id, @PathParam("id2") String id2, @PathParam("id3") String id3 )

    2) Even i tried to give @DefaultValue("1") @PathParam("Id"), @DefaultValue("2") @PathParam("Id2") 

 So in this case how we will manage these. As presently i am getting same error, as according to me if we give @DefaultValue then we shouldn't get error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will not be able to invoke your rest method if you don't specify ID - it is part of your URI: `/users/{id}`.

If you specify just `/users/` then you are invoking different rest method, for which you probably don't have an implementation - that's why you are getting error `404 - resource not found`.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply, but It is giving me same error in following senerio

1) If there are 3 paramaters and if i leave 1 blank
2) Even i tried to give @DefaultValue("1") @PathParam("Id"), @DefaultValue("2") @PathParam("Id2")

I dont know where i am wrong

Comment: What do you mean? Can you explain? Which scenario ? Cheers!

Comment: If you have 2 or 3 parameters and than this is different URI and different web service. You need different method, as this one accepts only 1 parameter.

Answer (score 0):

you have defined your endpoint to be @Path("/users/{id}" hence when you not providing the id it will return a HTTP 404 error meaning  @Path("/users/" does not exist and the call will not even hit your webservice.

Look at it this way if someone send you a package to your home address you can either open it or do something else with it, but if the package got a wrong address you won't get the package and you can't do anything with it. :)

Comment: If i use @DefaultValue("1") @PathParam("Id") then too it is giving same error, should i get this error or not??

Comment: sorry I didn't see your comment yesterday but I guess you got your answer from FazoMisiek

Comment: Yes you and FazoMisiek both have explained it well. I got the idea.